# Kubernetes services are not accessible through nodeport

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

we have set up a Kubernetes cluster version 1.13 using Kubespray on Baremetal. Currently, there are 3 masters and 3 workers. We have deployed some services with 3  replicas. We are using NodePort to expose services. Now the issue is that some of the services are not available on all the masters using NodePorts, they are available on some of the masters only. My understanding is that if we expose services using NodePort then It should be available through all the masters and workers.

Comment: Yes, NodePort works as you expecting. But provide more details, ouputs of your entities and logs

Comment: @VKR The logs of the kube-proxy container over the master node which was not accepting the traffic, were blank. There were no logs. Then I manually killed the container of kube-proxy and a new kube-proxy container got started automatically. Then the master started accepting traffic normally. Although It was a fix but I don't know the reason behind it. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/72712